# x-post October Travel comp

Tags: discussion, competitions, unanswered-questions

On travel we've had a September competition to bounty a bunch of questions to get them answered.  We've done a massive push to try and reduce our languishing unanswered questions, and it's been pretty successful.

As expats is very much our sister site and we want it to do well, we thought we'd try a cross-site competition to expose more people to it, and also to help out with some of the knowledge there.

As such, if anyone else would like to enter or help out for October, the [competition link is here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/the-october-challenge).

The idea being to try and answer as many expats questions as we can, but you have to get upvotes to move onto the next one.  So if you see someone from travel answering an old question, and you approve of the answer - even if you're not in the competition, don't forget to give them an upvote!

We'll also be tracking some expats stats there for unanswered questions, so don't forget to check in on that. Even if you don't want to join in on the competition, try and check out some of the old questions and see if you can help improve the stats.